# How do you find the following limit?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you find the following limit?

lim of $\frac{3\tan(x^3+y^3)-(x^3+y^3)}{(x^3+y^3)^3}$ as (x,y) approaches (0,0)

I did u sub for $x^3 + y^3$
So I got

lim of $\frac{3 \tan(u)-u}{u^3}$ as (u) approaches (0,0)
Then since it's "0"/0 I did Lopital's
and got,

lim of $\frac{3 sec^2(u)-1}{3u^2}$ as (u) approaches (0,0)
The 3's cancel out,
Then when I plug in the zeros, I get sec^2 (0) = 1
so "0"/0 again so loptial it. And after all is done I find out that the limit is 0.

Is my answer correct? Because someone else said the answer is infinity...

Comment: I edited a couple of lines of this to improve legibility.  You will be invited to learn a bit about the joys of TeX before long...

Comment: I believe you can use the "small-angle approximation" of $\tan u \rightarrow u$ to satisfy yourself that the numerator tends to $2u$ and thus "shrinks" more slowly than $u^3$ as $u$ approaches zero.  Therefore, the ratio does what?

Comment: Ok could you tell me why my method is wrong?

Comment: The 3's do not cancel. That is why you did not get $\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why they don't cancel??

Comment: $\frac{3\sec^2{u}-1}{3u^2}=\frac{\sec^2{u}-1/3}{u^2}\to\frac{\sec^2{0}-1/3}{0^2}=\frac{2/3}{0}=\infty$

Answer (score 2):

As you already noted, this limit is of the type "0/0". Hence we can evaluate it using [l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$$\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3\tan{u}-u}{u^3}=\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3\sec^2{u}-1}{3u^2}=
\lim_{u\to0} \frac{\sec^2{u}-1/3}{u^2}=\frac{\sec^2{0}-1/3}{0^2}=\frac{2/3}{0}=\infty$$

Note that the 3's do not cancel. That is why you did not get $\infty$.

To double-check the solution, we compute the limit using the more general [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series):

$$\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3\tan{u}-u}{u^3}=
\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3\left(u+\frac{u^3}{3}+\frac{2u^5}{15}+\mathcal{O}(u^6)\right)-u}{u^3}=
\lim_{u\to0} \frac{2u+u^3+\frac{2u^5}{5}+\mathcal{O}(u^6)}{u^3}=\infty$$

We see that the limit in question is indeed $\infty$.

**Note:** Earlier mistakes have been corrected.

Comment: Ok could you tell me why my method is wrong?

Comment: I think you mean "cannot use LHR when the limit is _not_ 0/0"...  @Jo Mo  What is the value of $3 \sec^2 u - 1$ for $u = 0$?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thank you for the remark. I have corrected the answer. I also have deleted my erroneous comments to avoid confusion.